# Error when Intalling google assistant in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am unable to install google assistant on Ubuntu Desktop.I am following the manual guide by google.

Link to guide:https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/setup

In the third step: Google guide given for device registration in the below photo

[image]

But on the console I can't find any such option and guide had given device registration tab.attached in below picture

[image]

But the console has no such option.

[image]

Can any one help me out for installing assisant on Ubuntu??
Thanks In Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Device Registration icon should show up in the onboarding flow when you create a new project. It is at the bottom of this page.

[image]